# Is there a way to anchor a non-toolstrip control to a toolstrip?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a window with a toolstrip.  Our users want a numeric spinner on the toolstrip.  Is there a way to anchor a control to a toolstrip?

Otherwise its just floating over the toolstrip and its placement is subject to varying screen resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [`ToolStripControlHost`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripControlHost(v=vs.110).aspx)?

```
var host = new ToolStripControlHost(yourSpinner, "yourName");
```

Comment: Didn't know about it... will look it up. ;)